# Работа со звуком в Java

Tags: аудио, java

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать некоторый пример проигрывателя звуковых файлов.
Пример выдаёт ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at SoundPlayer.newSound(SoundPlayer.java:94)
> at SoundPlayer.<init>(SoundPlayer.java:46)
> at SoundPlayer.main(SoundPlayer.java:83)

Подскажите, в чём может быть причина?

Код:

// Реализуем новый проигрыватель файлов. Воспроизведение с помощью SourceDataLine

// канала данных

```
import javax.swing.*;
import  java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundPlayer extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private File currentDir;
    private JComboBox soundChoice;
    private String oldFilename; // Предыдущее имя файла
    private JButton play; // Кнопка PLAY
    private boolean playing = false; // Управление потоком
    private SourceDataLine sourceLine; // Поток для звукового файла
    private int bufferSize; // Размер буфера в байтах
    private AudioInputStream source; // Канал для вывода звука
    private byte[] soundData; // Буфер для хранения значений звука
    private Thread thread; // Программный поток воспроизведения
    public SoundPlayer()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("SoundFile Player");
        setSize(250, 100);

        // Получить имена звуковых файлов
        currentDir = new File (System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
        {
            public boolean accept (File directory, String filename)
            {
                String name = filename.toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".wav")||name.endsWith(".au")||name.endsWith(".aif");

            }
        };
        String soundFiles[] = currentDir.list(filter);
        if (soundFiles == null|| soundFiles.length == 0 )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No Sound Files  - terminating","Sound Files Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        soundChoice = new JComboBox(soundFiles);
        soundChoice.setSelectedIndex(0);
        newSound(soundFiles[0]); // Это типа метод
        oldFilename = (soundFiles[0]); // Это тоже
        soundChoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                newSound((String)soundChoice.getSelectedItem());
            }
        }
                );
        // Настройка кнопки PLAY для воспроизведения текущего звукового файла
                play = new JButton("PLAY");
                play.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("PLAY"))
                        {
                            startPlay(); //Начинаем воспроизведение
                            play.setText("STOP"); // Меняем надпись на кнопке
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stopPlay();
                            play.setText("Text");
                        }
                    }
                }
                        );
                        Container content = getContentPane();
                        content.add(soundChoice);
                        content.add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
    }

    public void newSound(String filename)
    {
        // Задать текущий файл для воспроизведения

        File soundFile = new File(currentDir, filename);
        // Мы можем иметь уже воспроизводившийся фал
        if(sourceLine != null);  // Если имеется линия соединения
        {
          if(sourceLine.isActive()) // и если она ещё и активна,
          sourceLine.stop(); //  то остановим её
          play.setText("TEXT");
        }

        // Теперь проверить для потока и линии соединения
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream newSource = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            if(newSource.markSupported()) // Если можно маркировать поток?!
                newSource.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // то маркируем для будущего использования

        // Получить аудиоформат
            AudioFormat format = newSource.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            if(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(sourceInfo))
                // если тип соединения поддерживается, то получить новый канал
            {
                sourceLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
                bufferSize = (int)(format.getFrameSize()*format.getFrameSize()/2.0f);
                // открыть линию соединения
                sourceLine.open(format, bufferSize);
                // Новая линия в порядке - поэтому сохранить её
                source = newSource;
                // создать буфер для чтения
                soundData = new byte[bufferSize];
                // сохранить имя текущего файла
                oldFilename = filename;

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Lise not supported", "Line NOTSUPPORTED", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                // Востановить старый выбор
                soundChoice.setSelectedItem(oldFilename);
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is not supported", "Unsupported File Type", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            soundChoice.setSelectedItem(oldFilename);

        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line is not aviable","Line Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            soundChoice.setSelectedItem(oldFilename);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I/O Erroe", "I/O Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            soundChoice.setSelectedItem(oldFilename);

        }
    }

    // начать воспроизведение текущего файла
    public void startPlay()
    {
        if(sourceLine == null) //   Убедимя, что у нас есть канал
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No line available", "Play Problem", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        thread = new Thread(this); // создать поток воспроизведения
        playing = true; // флаг
        thread.start(); // запустить поток
    }
    // Остановить
    public void stopPlay()
    {
        playing = false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        sourceLine.start(); // Запустить линию
        int byteCount = 0; // прочитано байтов
        try
        {
            while(playing)
            {
                // читать поток
                byteCount = source.read(soundData, 0, soundData.length);
                if(byteCount == -1 ) // Если конец ввода
                {
                    if(source.markSupported())  // и мы можем восстановить поток
                        source.reset(); // вернуть его к началу
                    sourceLine.drain(); // Воспроизвести то, что осталось в буфере
                    playing = false;
                    break;
                }
                // Записать массив в канал
                sourceLine.write(soundData, 0, byteCount);

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        sourceLine.stop(); // Остановим канал
        play.setText("PLAY");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строчке 90

```
if(sourceLine != null);  // Если имеется линия соединения
```

уберите точку с запятой в конце строки.